# F450 Quadcopter frame torques

Tags: pid, drone

I'm building a quadcopter and programming it's flight controller which is running on a RP2040.
These are its main characteristics:

Frame: DJI F450

Radio: FlySky FS-I6

IMU: Adafruit BNO055 Breakout Board

Controller: Raspberry Pi Pico

Motors: 4x Brushless A2212/1000 kV

ESC: 4x 30A

Battery: 3s LiPo

Hardware is soldered on a matrix board and fastened to the center of the frame. LiPo battery is placed in between the matrix board and the bottom side PDU, hence its mass center is the same as the mass center of the body without the battery.

During the integration tests of the control software I noticed that the quad flips over its roll axis with constant throttle (20%) to the motors when attempting to takeoff.

I found [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344027717_Modelling_and_PID_control_system_integration_for_quadcopter_DJI_F450_attitude_stabilization) article about the simulation of controlling the f450 dynamics through a PID control loop. Their quadcopter configuration is identical to mine:
[image]

Equation (14) of the cited article state that:

[image: Torque matrix]

In particular the Torque roll relation is:
Tr = -(w1²)dxCt - (w2²)dxCt + (w3²)dxCt - (w4²)dxCt

When omega are constant for four Motors (wi = w) the expression reduces at

Tr = -3(w²)dxCt + (w²)dxCt = -2(w²)dxCt which is equal to zero only for w=0, throttle 0%.

According to this equation I will always have a roll torque which will cause the quad to be uncontrollable. In fact this is what I experimentally see but I think It's more likely that I am doing something wrong and also the paper contains a typo. Can I assume for simulation purposes that equation for roll torque is the following?

Tr = -(w1²)dxCt + (w2²)dxCt + (w3²)dxCt - (w4²)dxCt

(Motor 1 and 4, motor 2 and 3 contributes to the body torque with the same sign and the same magnitude when input are equals)

Comment: Hi! Just a follow-up question: why write a PID controller from scratch and not use a standard aerial autopilot board with PX4 or Ardupilot? It's not an easy feat to write this all from scratch so why not use existing solutions?

Comment: You're completely right, my intention is to write a flight controller which I know it is really challenging. Have a flying quadcopter will be just a consequence of my work, maybe